# Can I change the default cursor to a wait cursor for a set position within the form.design? C#

Tags: c#

I am new to using C# and I am wondering if there is a method for changing the cursor to a wait cursor for a specific area within the Form window.

In my case I would like the cursor to change to the wait cursor when it is processing data and the cursor is positioned over the Text Box output.

Is this at all possible?

Regards, 
Emily

Answer (score 1):

If your "specific area" is covered by a control, you can just set that control's `Cursor` property to `Cursors.WaitCursor`. In your case it seems like you have a `TextBox`:

```
yourTextBox.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
```

Otherwise, add a new control the the form:

```
var control = new Control();
// use the Location and Size properties to define your "area'
control.Location = ...;
control.Size = ...;
// set the cursor
control.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
yourForm.Controls.Add(control);
```

Comment: The first method works however, this only sets the cursor to a Wait.Cursor when it is hovered over the TextBox - Is there a way of associating this with the processing that is going on so that it returns to the default once the processing is complete?

Comment: @EmilyMartin After the processing you can just set it back to `Cursor.Current` or `Cursors.Arrow`.